# How to avoid specifying every leaf attribute in graphql query with gatsby

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I uploaded some json to my graphql using `gatsby-transformer-json` and `gatsby-source-filesystem`.

I would like to request an object of that data, which contains subfields.

When I try to make this request, I receive the error

```
Field \"sections\" of type \"DataJsonSections\" must have a selection of subfields. Did you mean \"sections { ... }\"?
```

Below is my json file. **I am trying to request the section called "Sections".** I would really like to find a way, so that I don't have to specify spiel and abbr for every section.

**My json file**

```
{
    "slogan": "some slogan",
    "drawIn": "Something to draw people in",
    "fullName": "My full title",
    "shortName": "My title",
    "metadata": {
        "desc": "...........",
        "title": "............"
    },
    "sections": {
        "about": {
            "spiel": "..........."
        },
        "web-design": {
            "abbr": "Websites",
            "spiel": ".............."
        },
        "app-design": {
            "abbr": "Apps",
            "spiel": "..........."
        },
        "seo": {
            "spiel": ".........."
        },
        "contact": {
            "title": "Contact",
            "subtitle": "Contact subtitle",
        }
    }
}
```

---

This is the request I would like to make, but I receive the error above when I do

```
query MyQuery {
  allDataJson {
    edges {
      node {
        sections
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

**Extra**

**Within my gatsby-config.js**(This is how I'm using `gatsby-transformer-json` and `gatsby-source-filesystem`)

```
`gatsby-transformer-json`,
{
  resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
  options: {
    name: `data`,
    path: `${__dirname}/src/data`
  }
},
```

Field "sections" of type "DataJsonSections" must have a selection of subfields

Comment: if node has subproperties then they must be used .... `..sections{ spiel } }...` .... change `sections` into array ( `[`, `]` brackets ), object has to use named nodes, not enumerated

Comment: @xadm If node, or if a node? And I don't know what you mean by enumerated. Is using an array the only way?

Comment: 'if a node' ... enumerated/array ... now you have to `sections {about { spiel` - note `about` 'in path' ... as an array you can `sections { spiel` ... loosing prop name, but no need to specify other nodes explicitely by name in path ('seo', 'contact' etc.) - move section title inside a node

Comment: You can look into https://github.com/taion/graphql-type-json, which (I think) will allow you to consume a JSON node directly. But, if all you want is data from JSON, why not just import it directly to your src file? Unless you have dozen of thousands of objects, I doubt it'll matter.

Comment: What about the GraphiQL tool? Can't you just build your query with the tool and copy/paste? This should avoid the error.

Comment: @DerekNguyen I dunno, it just feels cleaner to do it with graphql

Comment: @Stefan I can make it but I wanted to keep my queries small and cleaner